# Inside Struts 2 iterator tag, how to get current object for custom tag

Tags: java, validation, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

How to pass current object in custom tag. Tried by using `var="workobj"` in iterator, and by passing `"workobj"` in custom tag as shown below.But it returns `null`.

```
<s:iterator value="#request.work" var="workobj">
 <s:property> <!-- Returns current object -->

  <!-- Custom tag start--->
 <work:validate work="${workobj}" > 

 </work:validate> 
 <!-- Custom tag end--->
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `iterator` tag pushes the current element on `top` of the value stack. The Struts request wrapper has access to the `valueStack` searching the attributes with the keys from JSP EL expression.

```
<work:validate work="${top}" >
```